# How to improve Sauce Labs test execution speed for watir+ruby+rspec via Jenkins?

Tags: ruby, jenkins, webdriver, watir-webdriver, saucelabs

I have a problem when I run tests on Sauce Labs using watir + ruby + rspec via Jenkins CI. The entire test suite executes very slow.  How can I improve the execution speed?

Comment: Define "very slow".  Are individual tests running slowly or does the entire suite take a long time to execute?  Are you running tests in parallel?

Comment: Very slow entire suite. I've heard about parallel, but I'm not sure I understand how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve test suite execution speed I recommend to use 'parallel_tests' gem. Just add line `gem 'parallel_tests'` to your Gemfile, then in command prompt run:

```
bundle update                        #to setup new gem
bundle exec parallel_rspec /spec     #to run your tests in parallel
```

That's work for me. Thanks [orde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672197/orde) too.